# Is there a way to make the 3 lines for menu in the column caption always appear

Tags: ag-grid

I use ag-Grid but I find its not obvious that there is a column menu as i need to hover to make the 3 horizontal lines appear.
Can those lines always be visible?

Answer (score 0):

Set suppressMenuHide to true in your GridOptions